# How to add new row to data table without overwriting the existing record

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to add new records to a data table.  The data records will display in a data grid view and write to an XML file.  Every time I click the buttonCreate a record is created but it overwrites the existing entry instead of adding a new record.  How do I add new row to data table without overwriting the existing record?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create the DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Contact");
        //dt.TableName = "Contact";

        //create columns for the DataTable
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Id");
        dc1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        dc1.AutoIncrement = true;
        dc1.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dc1.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Age");
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Gender");

        //add columns to the DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc4);

        DataRow row;

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = textBoxName.Text;
        row["Age"] = textBoxAge.Text;
        row["Gender"] = textBoxGender.Text;

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        //insert data in the row
        //dt.Rows.Add(null, textBoxName.Text, textBoxAge.Text, textBoxGender.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        //create DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.DataSetName = "AddressBook";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        ds.WriteXml("Contacts.xml");
    }
}
```

Also, should I be creating the datatable in the form event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are recreating the datatable every time the button is clicked.  You should declare the datatable as a property of the Form1 class, create the columns in the Form1() method (this is called by the .net framework when the form is created (i.e when you start your application)), and then create your new row on the button click, add it to the datatable, and reset the gridview to point at the datatable to refresh it.

```
//create the DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Contact");
DataSet ds; 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //create columns for the DataTable
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Id");
    dc1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc1.AutoIncrement = true;
    dc1.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
    dc1.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

    //add columns to the DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender"));

    //create DataSet
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.DataSetName = "AddressBook";
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

}

private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Name"] = textBoxName.Text;
    row["Age"] = textBoxAge.Text;
    row["Gender"] = textBoxGender.Text;

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    ds.WriteXml("Contacts.xml");
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative solution. Although the current implementation will crash with the exception: "DataTable Already belongs to another DataSet."

Answer (score 1):

The record keeps getting overwritten by the next record because of this line of code:

```
 ds.WriteXml("Contacts.xml");
```

You need to append to the XML file, not override it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592269/appending-in-an-existing-xml-file-using-dataset) stackoverflow post.

If the application is quick and dirty then it's fine to do whatever you like inside the button handler. However if it is a real world application then you really need to have some sort of application architecture in place.